# Databricks save dataframe without creating subfolder

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to save a dataframe in Databricks using this code:

```
df.write.format("delta").save("abfss://my_container@my_storage.dfs.core.windows.net/my_path/filename.snappy.parquet")
```

But this creates additional subfolder `filename.snappy.parquet`, so the file is stored like `my_path/filename.snappy.parquet/filename.snappy.parquet` instead of desired `my_path/filename.snappy.parquet`.

How to save it without this additional unneeded subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

Spark `writes` the data to the folder and the path mentioned in `.save` is the folder name that spark creates.

- inside the folder there will be the `part` files that spark creates.

If you want to create the file with `specific name` then we need to rename the files as a post process([using dbutils.fs.mv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#--mv-command-dbutilsfsmv)) after the spark job writes the data.

```
dbutils.fs.mv("my_path/<file_name>", "my_path/filename.snappy.parquet/filename.snappy.parquet")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
df.write.format("delta").save("abfss://my_container@my_storage.dfs.core.windows.net/my_path/filename.snappy.parquet")
```

specify

```
df.write.format("delta").save("abfss://my_container@my_storage.dfs.core.windows.net/my_path/")
```

It will automatically create part files under my_path